# System process loses network connectivity when no users signed in

Tags: c++, windows, http, networking

I am attempting to run a program on a windows 10 machine, started via a system service in order to continue execution when no users are signed in. The program is written in c++ and polls a http web server on port 80 using [cpr](https://github.com/whoshuu/cpr), a c++ libcurl wrapper.

After a seemingly random length of time with no users logged in (with the computer on the logon screen), usually somewhere between 1 and 15 minutes, sometimes longer,  the http requests start consistently returning an error code of 0, which is obviously not a valid http error code, but it is what cpr returns as the status code.
The requests do not return to being successful until a user signs in again, where they function as intended indefinitely (i have conducted a 24 hour test).
The machine has all forms of sleep/hibernation disabled.

When checking Event Viewer, there is only one event type in the System log that falls within the area where the errors start occurring.

```
Log Name: System
Source: Schannel
Event ID: 36884
Level: Error
User: System
Message: The certificate received from the remote server does not contain the expected name. It is therefore not possible to determine whether we are connecting to the correct server. The server name we were expecting is client.wns.windows.com. The TLS connection request has failed. The attached data contains the server certificate.
```

The error seems unrelated, especially due to the server name, as well as the fact my programs http requests are not over TLS, but is reported regularly after the requests start failing, and stops when a user logs back in, allowing the http requests to succeed.
There are also seemingly sporadic Service Control Manager events stating that the start type of the Background Intelligent Transfer Service service was changed from auto start to demand start, or from demand start to auto start, but the event is reported all the time and does not seem to be specific to the period where my program fails to send requests.

Both the program and the service that starts it are functioning perfectly during this period, as they can report the errors to a log file with no issues. Just in case the program also creates SystemRequired and ExecutionRequired power requests by using the win32 api's PowerCreateRequest and PowerSetRequest functions.

I can find no logical reason for the requests just *not working* after a few minutes, and it is extremely infuriating. Please ask for any additional information in the comments.

Edit: The process code:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include <cpr/cpr.h>
 
#pragma comment(lib, "PowrProf.lib")
 
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    REASON_CONTEXT context;
    context.Version = POWER_REQUEST_CONTEXT_VERSION;
    context.Flags = POWER_REQUEST_CONTEXT_SIMPLE_STRING;
    context.Reason.SimpleReasonString = std::wstring(L"idle").data();
    HANDLE req = PowerCreateRequest(&context);
    if (req != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        PowerSetRequest(req, PowerRequestSystemRequired);
        PowerSetRequest(req, PowerRequestAwayModeRequired);
        PowerSetRequest(req, PowerRequestExecutionRequired);
    }
   
    while (true)
    {
        Sleep(10000);
        auto r = cpr::Post(
          cpr::Url{ "http://<IP>:80/update" },
          cpr::Header{ {"Authorization", "Basic " + "<BASE64_USER:PASS_PAIR>"}, {"Content-Type", "application/json"} },
          cpr::Body{ "{'data': 'test'}" },
          cpr::Timeout{ 5000 }
        );
    }
   
    if (req != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        PowerClearRequest(req, PowerRequestSystemRequired);
        PowerClearRequest(req, PowerRequestAwayModeRequired);
        PowerClearRequest(req, PowerRequestExecutionRequired);
        CloseHandle(req);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you set the equivalent of CURLOPT_VERBOSE in cpr? That might give you some clues.

Comment: "*started via a system service*" - why not implement it as its own system service? And did your service have dependencies setup for networking/TCP services? "*the http requests start consistently returning an error code of 0*" - please [edit] your question to show your actual code.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The reason behind the code being in a seperate process is that it just makes it easier to run and debug during development, and the code is simple and functions fine normally, but ill add it

Comment: @Botje It seems there used to be a verbose option, but it was removed so I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: Hack it in the library temporarily to get a clue what is going wrong?

Comment: @SilentPerson how do you know the status code is 0? There is no error handling in your HTTP code

Comment: @RemyLebeau My main program contains a lot of extraneous code and i cut it down to this, which included removing my debugging code. The extract i provided has the same issue on its own, so its not my other code, and i checked the error code by checking the status_code member of the `r` variable according to https://whoshuu.github.io/cpr/, and i know it is accurate because it returns 200 as expected when functioning

Comment: The computer in question is connected to a domain with a group policy applied, but i have reviewed the group policy and it has nothing that would cause this specific problem, and unfortunately i cannot provide it here as it contains sensitive information specific to our network. Is it possible that on the logon screen, the computer is being disconnected from the network due to no signed in user being available to authenticate? On the logon screen the machine is shown as connected though so that may not be the case.

Comment: @Botje i think it would be easier to just use a different library with verbose functionality, so i will try that next, because obviously i haven't really provided enough information for anyone to provide a working solution, and a valid http error code would be a step in the right direction

Comment: @SilentPerson "*Is it possible that on the logon screen, the computer is being disconnected from the network due to no signed in user being available to authenticate?*" - no. Network connectivity does not require user authentication. And various system services need network connectivity for their own purposes (time sync, background updates, etc)

Comment: @RemyLebeau it is a WPA2-Enterprise network, if that makes a difference